Find the area of the part of the paraboloid $z = x^2 + y^2$ that lies inside the cylinder $(x-4)^2 + (y-3)^2 = 4$
I know that the surface area is equal to:
$$A = \iint_{R} \sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)^2} \, dA, $$ , $\sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)^2} = \sqrt{1 + 4x^2 + 4y^2}.$
Switch to polar coordinates: $x = r\cos\theta, \quad y = r\sin\theta, $ so $ 0 \leq r \leq r^2 - 8r\cos\theta - 6r \sin\theta + 21$,     and   $  0 \leq \theta \leq \dfrac{\pi}{2} $ , integration limits are correct?.  Can someone help me finish this? Thank you!

You might have better luck applying the shift substitution $x = u + 4$, $y = v + 3$ first so that the domain of integration is the circle centered at the $(u, v)$-origin: $u^2 + v^2 = 4$ and then convert to polar coordinates: $u = r\cos\theta$, $v = r\sin\theta$.

I tried it, the integration limits become easier, but the integral remains very complicated :c.

You cannot set the boundaries for $r$ in terms of $r$ because it does not make sense. You need to express $r$ as the function of $\theta$. As you already have solved
$r^2−8\cdot r\cdot\cosθ−6\cdot r\sinθ+21=0$. Meaning that $r = \frac{8 \cos\theta + 6 \sin\theta \pm \sqrt{\left(8 \cos\theta + 6 \sin\theta\right)^2 - 84}}{2}$.

Now we solve for $x=\theta$ to find the boundaries

$(8\cos x + 6\sin x)^2 - 84 = 0.$

$(8\cos x + 6\sin x)^2 = 84.$

$8\cos x + 6\sin x = \pm \sqrt{84}.$

$8\cos x + 6\sin x = \pm 2\sqrt{21}.$
Express in the form $R\cos(x - \alpha)$
$R\cos(x - \alpha) = R(\cos x \cos \alpha + \sin x \sin \alpha).$
We can find $R$ using the Pythagorean identity:
R = $\sqrt{(R \cos \alpha)^2 + (R \sin \alpha)^2} = \sqrt{8^2 + 6^2} = \sqrt{64 + 36} = \sqrt{100} = 10.$
Now, we find $\alpha$:
$\tan \alpha = \frac{6}{8} = \frac{3}{4}.$

$\alpha = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right).$
So, the equation becomes:
$10 \cos(x - \alpha) = \pm 2\sqrt{21}.$
Now, we solve for (x):
$\cos(x - \alpha) = \pm \frac{2\sqrt{21}}{10} = \pm \frac{\sqrt{21}}{5}.$
Find the angles
$x - \alpha = \cos^{-1}\left( \frac{\sqrt{21}}{5} \right) + 2n\pi \quad \text{or} \quad x - \alpha = -\cos^{-1}\left( \frac{\sqrt{21}}{5} \right) + 2n\pi.$
Thus, the solutions for (x) are:
$x = \alpha + \cos^{-1}\left( \frac{\sqrt{21}}{5} \right) + 2n\pi \quad \text{or} \quad x = \alpha - \cos^{-1}\left( \frac{\sqrt{21}}{5} \right) + 2n\pi.$
where (n) is any integer.
So let $x1= \alpha + \cos^{-1}\left( \frac{\sqrt{21}}{5} \right)  \quad \text{and} \quad x2 = \alpha - \cos^{-1}\left( \frac{\sqrt{21}}{5} \right) $
So the integral for polar coordinates gonna look like this:
$\int_{x_2}^{x_1} \int_{\frac{8 \cos\theta + 6 \sin\theta - \sqrt{\left(8 \cos\theta + 6 \sin\theta\right)^2 - 84}}{2}}^{ \frac{8 \cos\theta + 6 \sin\theta + \sqrt{\left(8 \cos\theta + 6 \sin\theta\right)^2 - 84}}{2}} \sqrt{1 + 4r^2} \cdot r \, dr \, d\theta.$
You also can integrate without using polar coordinates
$\int_2^6 \int_{3 - \sqrt{4 - (x - 4)^2}}^{3 + \sqrt{4 - (x - 4)^2}} \sqrt{1 + 4x^2 + 4y^2} \, dy \, dx.$

Thank you so much
